# Air distiller - attempting to turn bottled wine into spirits

Tags: wine

Using an air distiller top table system.
I would like no ferment mash and just distill wine off the grocery store shelf.
But I need help,  with knowing how to make it happen.  There’s two videos that are available and both are not good.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the [Still Spirits Air Still](https://stillspirits.com/products/turbo-air-still). It's rubbish and will produce a fairly terrible brandy.

However, don't let that dissuade you from giving distillation a go. For the Air Still in particular, fill it up with wine and operate it according to the instruction booklet. You could [try to make cuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Lc7IhcUVyA&t=23s) but it will be very difficult due to the tiny size of the air still and the amount of smearing.

The instructions will probably tell you to carbon filter it - ignore this. The Still Spirits system is designed to make neutral spirits that are flavoured with essences from their Essence range, but for a brandy you want to retain the flavours from the original wine.

Here are some great YouTube channels on home distillation:

- [Still It](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCThY8lOKKkVDd9HVBT59zCg)
- [Barley and Hops](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCatCieEI4cPNteKXzBomVMQ)